# Dangling memory/ unallocated memory issue

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, memory-management

I've this piece of code, which is called by a timer Update mechanism.

However, I notice, that the memory size of the application, while running, continuously increases by 4, indicating that there might be a rogue pointer, or some other issue.

```
void RtdbConnection::getItemList()
{

std::vector<CString> tagList = mItemList->getItems();
//CString str(_T("STD-DOL1"));
PwItemList* pil = mPwSrv->GetItemList();
CPwItem pw ;

for(auto it = tagList.begin(); it != tagList.end(); ++it)
{

    pw = mPwSrv->GetItem(*it);
    pil->AddItem(&(PwItem)pw);

}

pil->AddInfo(DB_DESC);  //Description
pil->AddInfo(DB_QALRM); // Alarm Status
pil->AddInfo(DB_QUNAK); //UNACK status
pil->AddInfo(DB_AL_PRI); // Priority of the alarm tag

pil->ExecuteQuery();


int i = 0;

for (auto it = tagList.begin();  i < pil->GetInfoRetrievedCount() && it != tagList.end(); i+=4, it++) 
{       
    //item = {0};
    CString str(*it);
    PwInfo info = pil->GetInfo(i);
    CString p(info.szValue().c_str());
    bool isAlarm = pil->GetInfo(i+1).bValue();
    bool isAck = pil->GetInfo(i+2).bValue();
    int priority  = pil->GetInfo(i+3).iValue();

    item = ItemInfo(str, p, isAlarm, isAck, priority);
    //int r = sizeof(item);
    mItemList->setInfo(str, item);   // Set the details for the item of the List


}

delete pil;
pil = NULL;


}
```

I cannot seem to find a memory block requiring de-allocation here. Nor is there any allocation of memory when I step inside the following function :

```
mItemList->setInfo(str, item);
```

which is defined as :

```
    void ItemList::setInfo(CString tagname, ItemInfo info)
{
    int flag = 0;
    COLORREF tempColour;
    std::map<CString, ItemInfo>::iterator tempIterator;
    if ( (tempIterator = mAlarmListMap.find(tagname)) !=mAlarmListMap.end() )
    {
        //remove the current iteminfo and insert new one
        if(mAlarmListMap[tagname].getPriority() != info.getPriority() && (mAlarmListMap[tagname].getPriority()!=0))
        {
            mAlarmListMap[tagname].updatePriority(info.getPriority());
            mAlarmListMap[tagname].mPrioChanged = TRUE;
        }
        else
        {
            mAlarmListMap[tagname].mPrioChanged = FALSE;
            ((mAlarmListMap[tagname].getPrevPriority() != 0)?(mAlarmListMap[tagname].ResetPrevPriority()):TRUE);
            mAlarmListMap[tagname].setPriority(info.getPriority());
        }


        mAlarmListMap[tagname].setDescription(info.getDescription());
        mAlarmListMap[tagname].setAlarm(info.getAlarmStat());
        mAlarmListMap[tagname].setAlarmAck(info.getAckStat());
        tempColour = mColourLogic->setUpdatedColour(mAlarmListMap[tagname].getAlarmStat(), mAlarmListMap[tagname].getAckStat(), flag);
        mAlarmListMap[tagname].setColour(tempColour);

        if(!(info.getAlarmStat() || info.getAckStat()))
        {

                flag = 1;
                mAlarmListMap[tagname].mIsRTN = true;
                mAlarmListMap[tagname].setDisplayCondition(false);

        }
        else
        {
            mAlarmListMap[tagname].setDisplayCondition(true);
        }

                //((mAlarmListMap[tagname].mIsRTN == true)?

    }
    else
       { 
           tempIterator =  mAlarmListMap.begin();
           tempColour = mColourLogic->fillColourFirst(info.getAlarmStat(), info.getAckStat());
           info.setColour(tempColour);
           mAlarmListMap.insert(tempIterator, std::pair<CString,ItemInfo>(tagname,info));

    }



}
```

I tried juggling with the allocations, but the increase is always a constant 4.

Could anyone kindly look and highlight where the issue could be? 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: How would it make a difference? And what shall I do to fix it?

Comment: Tried with the change. Did not work. Still the same increase in memory.

Comment: Compile with symbols and run your program using a memory checker, like for example Valgrind (http://valgrind.org) to debug memory issues.

Comment: But can anyone notice, superficially, any rogue allocation of memory, and which is not de-allocated?

Comment: As you mention the code it called by some other function, are you sure the leak comes from the code shown?

Comment: I have commented every other piece of code which might be called in the `Timercheck()` function. The first is the only one called, and which in turn calls the second one.

Comment: What keeps you from doing as I proposed in my ealier comment, that is using a memory checker? Issues of this question's kind are what they are made for.

Comment: looks like a bug here `pil->AddItem(&(PwItem)pw);` - you're adding an address on the stack, this is dangerous.

Comment: Valgrind works on Windows? I seem to recall that it didn't. If not, what other memory  checker can I use?